# How to prefetch images into array and display them in browser in infinite loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can any one guide me on how to achieve this.. I am listing them in pointers..

1. A linux binary captures frames from the locally attached webcamera
   and stores them in a folder. This is a continuous process. The
   images are stored numerically.
2. I have a webserver which gives a output of the latest images received from the webcamera. This is a PHP file which gets the recent most image received and prints out.
3. What I have now is a javascript which refreshes the image every second and displays in the img tag.
4. Though it works the output is slow and updates slowly one frame at a time.
5. I am trying to display the images quickly and in a way it should
   look like a mjpeg movie being played (not that it has to be so good
   as I learned from the forums that the http does have its overhead)

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function refresh(){
document.images["pic1"].src="/latimage.php?camid=$selectedcamid&ref=" + new Date();
setTimeout('refresh()', 1000);}
if(document.images)window.onload=refresh;
</script>
```

```html
<img src='/latimage.php?camid=$selectedcamid' id='pic1'>
```

1. Above code works perfect. But my unsatisfied mind wants to display the frames obtained from the webcam quickly..like displaying atleast 3 to 4 frames per second.
2. As I understood from my searches so far it is not too feasible to do
   the refresh act too quickly as the HTTP process does take time.
3. I am trying to find some details on getting this done using a method
   by which I can prefetch 100 frames into a image array (I would call
   it buffering) and start displaying one image at a time at the rate
   of 3 images / second.
4. Whiles displaying the images the older images should be removed from
       the array and the latest ones fetched should be inserted in the end.
5. Thus the looping is infinite.

I am sorry for asking too many questions..I am unable to find any proper direction to start off with. I can do the above in .net windows application quite easily but in web browser I am unable to get any ideas. I am not sure if jQuery image array or json or simple javascript would do.

I need some guidance please..

Comment: +1 for a well thought out approach, goal and methodology.  Here's to hoping a brilliant mind can come up with what you need.  I am curious however, as to what project this is for... hopefully not the cam industry.

Comment: This is kind of the point of using streams: A stream of images will be equivalent to every single frame being a key-frame, meaning a large amount of data. This is an old problem producing solutions such as stream formats where you only need a key-frame now and then, and in between only visual changes. This allows for much smaller size for the non-key-frames as much less data is transferred and decoded (typically) which=performance. Requiring full frame transfer sort of ends with a circle back to the times when it was (and is) a problem. Solution: use a streaming approach (see VLC etc.).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to capture the camera output to disk, then I suggest capturing the camera output as video (at 3 FPS) and then streaming that video file to your browser using WebSockets. [Here](http://phoboslab.org/log/2013/09/html5-live-video-streaming-via-websockets) is an example of doing that. If you are willing to run nginx on your server then [live_thumb](https://github.com/jbochi/live_thumb) is a complete solution that captures and streams video via WebSockets.

On the other hand, if your goal is just to view the output of the camera and you don't need to store the video, you could consider using WebRTC and running a browser at both ends and then just hooking up the media stream. In other words one browser (perhaps a headless variant) would run on the system with your camera and would stream the video to your other browser using WebRTC. With WebRTC you could get much higher frame rates and your bandwidth would probably still be significantly lower than sending individual images at a slow frame rate.